# Вывод характеристик в scroller.tpl Cs-cart

Tags: php, cs-cart

Нужно на главной странице в scroller.tpl вывести определенные характеристики товаров, есть массив $product но в нем нету характеристик (features), с базы тянуть не вариант... В категории выводить их просто достаточно - get_features: true, и в переменную-массив $product добавляются характеристики, как на главной сделать не знаю.

Comment: "с базы тянуть не вариант." А откуда же им тогда взяться?

Comment: Я имею ввиду в моем случае не вариант, архитектура мне не ясна